Issue with groupID for Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Consumer Actuator Health with SSL
I have a spring cloud kafka stream consumer application. This application connects to Kafka over TLS. There is a strict naming requirement for the group.id which we are able to easily accomplish via spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<input-binding-name>.group property.
The issue arises when we hit the actuator endpoint. When we hit the actuator health it creates a consumer with groupID null and clientID consumer-null-#. This violates the naming requirement of my groupID and hence healthcheck always shows Binder as Down
I tried to pass group.id as spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.group.id. But that property gets ignored with the following message:-
Ignoring provided value(s) for 'group.id'. Use spring.cloud.stream.default.group or spring.cloud.stream.binding.<name>.group to specify the group instead of group.id
I tried using spring.cloud.stream.default.group as well but to no avail. Has anyone faced such an issue and is there a solution for the same.

This is a gap in the binder health indicator. We should improve that. I created an issue to address this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2949

Why does the binder health check show DOWN? How do you access the endpoint? I wonder how the group config has an impact on that. Could you elaborate on that?

A new property was added in the binder to specify the group.id for the consumer used in the health indicator: spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.healthIndicatorConsumerGroup. This change is only in 4.1.2-SNAPSHOT. Please try that and see if that works for you.

Thank you @sobychacko. However, we are using spring boot parent 2.7.12 and spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 3.2.8. The version 4.1.2 seems to support only Spring Boot 3.XX. Is it possible to make similar changes for kafka-binder 3.2.8?

Hi, these versions are out of support. https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#support and https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support. That means there won't be any more OSS releases for those versions. Any chance you can upgrade? The best we can do is to backport the change to 4.0.x which still has a commercial support left.

Thank you @sobychacko. I ran the code with spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 4.0.1 and it seems to work fine. If you could backport the changes to 4.0.X I can test and let you know.

@sobychacko, could you please let me know if the changes are backported and what version I can use to test ?

My apologies - On looking at things again from the support angle, the 4.0.x version of Spring Cloud Stream is already out of OSS support. See the support timeline here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#support. This means that there won't be another OSS release for this version of Spring Cloud Stream. You need to depend on the 4.1.x versions. 4.0.x is still under the commercial support timelines. If that is something you can consume commercially, then we can backport it on the commercial version. Please let us know.
